# django is it possible to access data stored in forms?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am using django-cms. I have my own product model, which has attribute

```
page = models.ManyToManyField(Page, verbose_name=_('Page'), related_name="products")
```

`Page` is django-cms class. In admin interface, i can add new page, which has field Slug. Now in `class Page` there is no field slug.

That slug field is in forms.py

```
slug = forms.CharField(label=_("Slug"), widget=forms.TextInput())
```

Is it possible to access that field in code?

Comment: Once a field is declared in a form, it is still available for you in your view by accessing cleaned_data['formField']. Once you have access to the cleaned_data you can do whatever you want with them (save them to a model or multiple models etc..depending on your use case)

Comment: If that would be my case, then yes. But i need to get that data in my custom middleware. This happens BEFORE page is rendered, so i can't get it from cleaned_data.

Comment: your custom middleware class would still have the request object, you just need to override https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/#process-request or other methods that follow this.

Comment: Yes, i have that function `process_request(request)` . But problem i made this function to work when im in product detail page: `if match and match.url_name == 'product_detail':`. So i can't get post data from this page. Url of admin interface: http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/admin/cms/page/46/

Comment: Each middleware can have its own process_request.

Comment: If I understand it right, I suppose you should write something like below: if 'admin/cms/page/' (or use reverse func to be much cleaner) in request.path then do something and if you're not returning any httpresponse object, don't forget to return None so the request is processed further.

Comment: Yes you understood me right. But not sure if this works, because:
1. If user is not admin, then this url could not be reached.
2. In my `process_request(request)` function at point where it goes through if statement `if match and match.url_name == 'product_detail:`, here i need to get that slug.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake. Django-cms `class Page` actually has function:

`def get_slug(self, language=None, fallback=True, version_id=None, force_reload=False):`

In my custom middleware just called that function and solved it.